# Lines don't align in rastertoPolygons

Tags: r, raster

I am having trouble with aligning grids on a plot I made. Basically the plots show the result of a 34x34 matrix where each point has a value of 0,1,2,3 and is colored based on this. The lines which outline the cells do not match up perfectly with the coloring of the cells. My code and image are below.

```r
library(raster)

r<-raster(xmn=1,xmx=34,ymn=1,ymx=34,nrows=34,ncols=34)

data1<-read.csv(file ="mat_aligned.csv",row.names = 1)

numbers<-data.matrix(data1)

r[]<-numbers

breakpoints<-c(-1,0.1,1.1,2.1,3.1)

colors<-c("white","blue","green","red")

plot(r,breaks=breakpoints,col=colors)

plot(rasterToPolygons(r),add=TRUE,border='black',lwd=3)
```

[image]

I would appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the base R plot and the drawing of the grid use different plotting systems. The polygons will stay constant relative to the plotting window (they will appear narrower as the window shrinks), and won't preserve their relationship to the underlying plot axes, whereas the coloured squares will resize to preserve shape. You'll probably find that you can get your grid to match better by resizing your window, but of course, this isn't ideal.

The best way to get round this is to use the specific method designed for plotting `SpatialPolygonDataFrame`, which is the S4 class produced by `rasterToPolygons`. This is, after all, how you're "meant" to create such a plot.

Here's a reprex (obviously I've had to make some random data as yours wasn't shared in the question) :

```r
library(raster)
r <- raster(xmn = 1, xmx = 34, ymn = 1, ymx = 34, nrows = 34, ncols = 34)
r[] <- data.matrix(as.data.frame(replicate(34, sample(0:3, 34, TRUE))))
colors <- c("white","blue","green","red")
spplot(rasterToPolygons(r), at = 0:4 - 0.5, col.regions = colors)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect! And yes I actually had gotten it to align perfectly once and it wasn't reproducible. I must have resized the window and gotten lucky. That makes sense. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help if you not provide a minimal self-contained reporducible example. Something like this

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(xmn=1,xmx=34,ymn=1,ymx=34,nrows=34,ncols=34)
values(r) <- sample(4, ncell(r), replace=T)
p <- rasterToPolygons(r)
plot(r)
lines(p)
```

I see what you describe, even though it is minimal. A work-around could be to only plot the polygons

```
colors<-c("white","blue","green","red")
plot(p, col=colors[p$layer])
```